# Angular2 Use sort pipe only when certain value or boolean is true

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

My markup looks like this:

```
 <li *ngFor="let user of usersList | orderBy : ['name']; let i = index;">
```

So is there anyway to apply orderBy pipe only when certain boolean is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
<li *ngFor="let user of usersList | orderBy : [value ? 'name' : '']; let i = index;">
```

Another option would be creating a wrapper pipe that takes a parameter and uses the orderBy pipe conditionally.

*EDIT

As @OliverRenner states, `orderBy` is no longer offered by Angular in 2.0. The above assumes that you have written your own `orderBy` implementation.
See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filter-pipe

Answer (score 0):

since orderBy does not exist in angular2, you need a custom pipe anyways (if you want to use a pipe at all) .. therefore you can pass the boolean into this pipe and only apply sorting when true.